# Нарисовать текст js

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо нарисовать вот такой текст в js с помощью document.write(), помогите пожалуйста буду благодарен :)

Comment: Минус ставлю пока Вам :).

Comment: @Igor я уже составляю ответ на основе вопроса :^

Comment: @MoloF Хм. Я уже составил ответ *на основе вопроса*. И даже написал его в моем предыдущем комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.write(`
 *******  *******  *******  *            *
 *              *              *              *          *
 *              *              *              *       *
 *              *              *              *     *
 *******  *****      *****      *   *
             *  *              *              **
             *  *              *              *     *
             *  *              *              *         *
 *******  *              *******  *            *
`);
```

```css
body {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```